# c++ overload operator() for assigning value in a dynamic 2D array

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to overload () operator to assign value into a dynamically allocated 2D array, here is my code --

```
class test {
    private:
        int** data ; int row, col ;

    public:
        test(int row = 2, int col = 2)  {
            this->row = row ; this->col = col ;
            this->data = new int*[this->row] ;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < this->row ; i++)
                this->data[i] = new int[this->col] ;
        }

        ~test() {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < this->row ; i++)
                delete [] this->data[i] ;
            delete [] this->data ;
        }

        const int operator() (int row, int col) { // read operation
            return this->data[row][col] ;
        }

        int& operator() (int row, int col) { // write operation
            return this->data[row][col] ;
        }

        // for printing
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &os, const test &t);
};
```

In the operator() write operation, I am trying to return the value by reference so that I can assign value like this --

```
test t(4,4) ;
t(2,2) = 5 ;
```

But it does not compile, says that I can't do such kind of overloading, so what should be the correct constructs that could be used to achieve `t(2,2) = 5` type of statement ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first overload must be in form:

```
int operator() (int row, int col) const
```

Not

```
const int operator() (int row, int col)
```

And it is not the read operation, it is used when an object of your type is created as `const`, this overload will be used, if not `const`, other overload will be used, both for reading and writing.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have overloads that only differ in return type. In order to get the effect you want, add a const:

```
int operator() (int row, int col) const {
    return this->data[row][col];
}
```

And keep the other overload

```
int &operator(int row, int col) {
    return this->data[row][col];
}
```

You *can* overload methods with a `const` at the end of the method declaration. What this does is the following:

1. If the object created is a `const test`, then `int operator()(int row, int col) const` will be called
2. If the object created is a `test` (no `const`), then `int &operator(int row, int col)` will be called

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the correct reason why the compiler is giving the error! Please explain

Comment: your answer does not help, I did not post this to find error in the code, my question was how overload the `()` operator so that I can do `t(2,2) = 5` kind of coding construct.